# How to find the max value of unknown integer type

Tags: c++

How can I find the maximal integer value of an unknown type?
Is there something more efficient than this:

```
template<class T>
T test(T i) {
    if (((T)-1) > 0)
       return -1;
    T max_neg = ~(1 << ((sizeof(T)*8)-1));
    T all_ones = -1;
    T max_pos = all_ones & max_neg;
    return max_pos;
}
```

Comment: Note: the given code was probably wrong. The early `-1` test and return for unsigned types is OK, but then: for `max_neg`: first `CHAR_BIT` may be more than `8`, and anyway you're shifting a `1` into the _sign bit_, which I think is undefined; and for `all_ones`: `-1` may _not_ be "all ones", for example on a one's complement or sign-and-magnitude machine. And for the logic: it seems that `max_neg` would already be equal to `max_pos`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). Since C++11, this function is `constexpr` and thus evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: Even pre-C++11, the function was generally inline, and the compiler would evaluate it at compile-time.  (But because this wasn't required, you couldn't use it in contexts which required a compile time constant.)

Answer (score 5):

`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This is good: `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or if you like boost: `boost::integer_traits<T>::max()`.

Comment: *"Linear complexity for both."* - Huh, linear complexity on what, the non-existent input? It's a simple constant that they return.

Comment: @ChristianRau Pre C++11, the standard didn't impose any complexity, so an implementation _could_ make it linear complexity (say by incrementing until the incrementation resulted in a smaller value).  Of course, it's probably safe to say that none were that stupid.